# Wordpress: query for Author display the last person who modified the page and not the "owner" of the page

Tags: php, wordpress

This code works, but not properly

tldr: I've custom page templates on WordPress, I need to show who compiled the technical page (the person who created) but with my query if a person update the page it shows the name of who modified and not the person who created the page, any help?

This is the code:

```
     <span>Scheda: <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>"title="<?php printf( esc_attr( get_the_author() ) ); ?>" rel="author">
<strong itemprop="name"><?php the_author(); ?></strong>  </a>
     </span>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.